# How to extract the last 8 elements of each item on an array using BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column that is an array, like

> ["551199999999","55129999999999","5532999999999]

Using BigQuery, I used `JSON_EXTRACT_STRING_ARRAY(column)` and I get the items split on a list. Now, I want to get the last 8 string of each item of the array, I've trid `RIGHT(JSON_EXTRACT_STRING_ARRAY(column))` but I got an erro. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to **UNNEST** an array first and apply **RIGHT()** function to each item of the array like below.

```sql
 WITH sample AS (
   SELECT '["551199999999","55129999999999","5532999999999"]' json
 )
 SELECT RIGHT(item, 8) 
   FROM sample, UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(json)) item;

-- Query results
+-----+----------+
| Row |   f0_    |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | 99999999 |
|   2 | 99999999 |
|   3 | 99999999 |
+-----+----------+
```

And prefer to use new JSON functions instead of using legacy ones.

[image]

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#standard_json_extraction_functions_recommended